# How to add column header to a csv file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, csv

I am in process of writing a monitoring script on different servers.

My requirement is to collect the date in every 30 mins from both the servers, combine the data and send through mail.

Now, where I am stuck is when getting the data to a csv file i need to add column headings which im unable to do.

Code snippet on srv1

```
#!/bin/bash 

EAI=`netstat | grep 16001 | wc -l` 
Date=`date` 
DM=`psme | grep -i DM_EAI | wc -l`        

while true; do
     echo $Date $EAI
     sleep 1800 done  > eai_js_srv1.csv   
while true; do
     echo $Date $DM
     sleep 1800 done  > dm_eai_srv1.csv
```

code snippet on srv2

```
#!/bin/bash  
EAI=`netstat | grep 16001 | wc -l`  
Date=`date`  
DM=`psme | grep -i DM_EAI | wc -l`   

while true; 
    do echo $Date $DM sleep 1800 
done > eai_js_srv2.csv   

while true; 
    do echo $Date $EAI sleep 1800 
done > dm_eai_srv2.csv
```

after this im combining the files from the 2 servers as below:

```
join -a1 -a2 eai_js_srv1.csv eai_js_srv2.csv > eai_js_counts.csv  
join -a1 -a2 dm_eai_srv1.csv dm_eai_srv2.csv > dm_eai_counts.csv
```

Since im using while loop so data would be appending to the same file in every 30mins so now i need the desired output as:

eai_js_counts.csv:

```
Timestamp                           BRM Servers 
                                    611       610   
1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST              176       99   
1/28/2013 06:00 AM PST              150       115
```

dm_eai_counts.csv:

```
Timestamp                           BRM Servers 
                                    611       610  
1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST              4         5  
1/28/2013 06:00 AM PST              4         5
```

Comment: what is the current output?

Comment: The question was formatted about as badly as possible, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)!

Comment: If information is appended, you just need to put the headers the first time, right? So what you could do is check if file exists. If it does not, print header; otherwise, don't.

Comment: You're writing the same data every 30 minutes!  (That is, you are not gathering new data.  Rather, you collect data once and then write that same data every 30 minutes forever, ignoring the actual value at the time the data is written.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash  

F=eai_js_srv2.csv
D=dm_eai_srv2.csv
cat > $F << EOF # Write a header to the file $F
Timestamp                           BRM Servers 
                                    611       610
EOF

cat > $D << EOF # Write a header to the file $D
Timestamp                           BRM Servers 
                                    611       610
EOF

# Write data every 1800 seconds.  
while sleep 1800; do
    exec >> $F  # Direct output to file $F
    date | tr '\n' ' '
    netstat | grep 16001 | wc -l
    exec >> $D # Direct output to $D
    date | tr '\n' ' '  
    psme | grep -i DM_EAI | wc -l
done
```

Comment: Hi William/Fedorqui, I am not overwriting the data as nos do change every 30 mins,so appending the data to same file after every 30 mins. Hope i am bit clear this time.

Comment: @stuti  Unfotunately, the code posted in your question is appending exactly the same text every 30 minutes.  It is *not* computing new data every 30 minutes.  If this solution does not work for you, please explain why.

Comment: Hi William, im getting below output: `Timestamp                           BRM Servers 
                                     611     610
Mon Feb  4 01:11:37 PST 20136
Mon Feb  4 01:12:37 PST 20136
Mon Feb  4 01:13:38 PST 20136` what i need is proper space between time and the command output i.e `Timestamp                           BRM Servers 
                                    611     610
Mon Feb  4 01:11:37 PST 2013         6
Mon Feb  4 01:12:37 PST 2013         6
Mon Feb  4 01:13:38 PST 2013         6` Could you please suggest how that can be achieved? Thanks

Comment: Add a space with `printf` or `echo -n`.  eg `date ...; printf ' '; netstat ...`

Comment: @Williams,thanks it worked. Also, could you please tell me how to merge 2 files based on 1st column 348.csv & 349.csv when joining them using `join -a1 -a2 -1 2 -2 2 348.csv 349.csv` not getting a proper output. what is expected is                                      `Timestamp                           BRM Servers  
                                    348       349     
1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST              176       99  
1/28/2013 06:00 AM PST              150       115  `               and in an order.

Comment: If it works, accept the answer and ask the other question in a different question!